# Polynomial satisfying functional inequality

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be polynomial function satisfying $0<xf(y)<yf(x)$ $\forall \; x ,y$ such that $0<x<y<1$ and $f(0)=0$, then choose correct options

(A) $f'(x)<f(1)$

(B) $f(1)<2 \displaystyle \int_0^{1} f(x) \; dx$

(C) $3f\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)>2f\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$

(D) $6 f\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)<5f\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)$

How do we deal with these type of inequality. Correct options are **A,B,D**

For option C and D, I shuffled inequality as

$\dfrac{1}{y} f(y)<\dfrac{1}{x} f(x)$ then put $x=1/6$ and $y=1/5$, then

$5 f\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)<6f\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)$ but that should make option D wrong and option C correct. I have no idea on how to approach option A and B. Please provide some insight

Comment: Option D is wrong. Example $f(x)=x-x^2$.

Comment: Option A is also wrong for this example, if you take $x=1/3$

Comment: If you will make Taylor series of $yf(x)-xf(y)$ at $y\to x+0$, you can get $f(x)<xf'(x)$.